# How to avoid a zero determinant matrix in a system of linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

Suppose that I have a matrix $X$ in a (homogeneous) system of linear equations of the form $AXB=0$ and I want to find a **non-trivial** matrix $X$ (i.e. $X \neq 0$). A possible solution is given by constraining matrix $X$ to have unitary norm, i.e., $\|X\|_F^2=1$. In this case I can solve:
$$(B^\top \otimes A)vec(X)=0$$
by taking the SVD of the matrix $(B^\top \otimes A)$ and set for instance $vec(X)$ equal to a right eigenvector of the matrix $(B^\top \otimes A)$ associated to a singular value equal to zero.

But how can I enforce other kind of constraints, for instance that $\operatorname{det}(X) \neq0$? Do I have any closed form solution like the SVD above?

Notice that the matrix $Q=B^\top \otimes A$ is in general non-square.

Comment: If $\det(A),\det(B)\neq 0$ it is impossible to find a non-trivial matrix $X$, because then $\det(X)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  $X$ is non-trivial if $det(A)$ or  $det(B) = 0$. But suppose this condition is verified, how can I enforce in general, given $Q \operatorname{vec}(X)=0$, that $ \operatorname{det}(X) \neq 0$? Since I vectorize the matrix $X$, how can check that?

Comment: @V I'm confused because you don't explicitly say this: does a "non-trivial" matrix specifically refer to a matrix with non-zero determinant?

Comment: For non-trivial I mean the solution is different from the all-zero solution. I added this now on the description of the question.

Comment: @V But your method using the right singular vector already produces a solution that is not the all-zeros matrix, assuming such a solution exists.

Comment: True, but it does not enforce the property "determinant different from zero". It only enforces the property "norm is equal to one".

Answer (score 1):

Note that if a solution to $AXB = 0$ exists with $X$ square of size $n$ and $\det(X)\neq 0$, then by [Sylvester's rank inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) we have
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= \operatorname{rank}(AXB) 
\\ & \geq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(XB) - n 
= \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) - n,
\end{align}
$$
so that $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \leq n$. Equivalently, $\operatorname{rank}(B) \leq \dim \ker(A)$. If $A$ and $B$ satisfy this condition, then a matrix $X$ will satisfy $AXB = 0$ iff it satisfies the following.

> **Condition 1:** For every $v \in \operatorname{Im}(B)$, $Xv \in \ker(A)$.

One solution $X$ can be generated as follows. Let $u_1,\dots,u_k$ be an orthonormal basis for the kernel of $A$, which can be obtained using the right singular vectors of $A$. Extend this to a full orthonormal basis $u_1,\dots,u_n$ of $\Bbb R^n$. Let $v_1,\dots,v_r$ (with $r\leq k$) be a basis for the image of $B$, extend it to a basis $v_1,\dots,v_n$ of $\Bbb R^n$. Let $U$ denote the matrix with columns $v_1,\dots,v_n$ and let $V$ denote the matrix with columns $u_1,\dots,u_n$.

The matrix $X = UV^T$ will necessarily satisfy $AXB = 0$, and we will have $|\det(X)| = 1 \neq 0$.

---

We can say a bit more than this. Let $U= [U_1 \ \ U_2]$, $V = [V_1\ \ V_2]$ where $U_1$ has $k$ columns and $V_1$ has $k$ columns. Suppose that $X = UYV^T$, so that
$$
X = \pmatrix{U_1 & U_2}\pmatrix{Y_{11} & Y_{12}\\Y_{21} & Y_{22}}\pmatrix{V_1 & V_2}^T
\\ = U_1Y_{11}V_1^T + U_1Y_{12}V_2^T + U_2Y_{21}V_1^T + U_2 Y_{22}V_2^T.
$$
For any $v \in \operatorname{im}(B)$, $V_2^Tv = 0$, which means that
$$
Xv = (U_{1}Y_{11})(V_1^Tv) + (U_{2}Y_{21})(V_1^Tv).
$$
Whenever $U_2Y_{21} \neq 0$, it holds that $(U_{21}Y_{21})(V_1^Tv) \neq 0$ for some $v \in \operatorname{im}(B)$. For this $v$, it holds that $Xv \notin \ker(A)$, which is to say that $X$ does not satisfy the Condition 1. Conversely, if $U_2Y_{21} = 0$, it is easy to see that $X$ will satisfy Condition 1. Thus, $X$ will be a solution iff $U_2Y_{21} = 0$, which holds iff $Y_{21} = 0$.

Thus, $X$ is a solution to the equation $AXB = 0$ iff it is of the form
$$
X = \pmatrix{U_1 & U_2}\pmatrix{Y_{11} & Y_{12}\\0 & Y_{22}}\pmatrix{V_1 & V_2}^T.
$$
This matrix will be invertible iff both $Y_{11}$ and $Y_{22}$ are invertible.

Comment: Thank you Ben. This is of great help. Can this be extended to the case in which I have a non square matrix $Q$ and I want an $X$ such that $Q vec(X)=0$ and $det(X) \neq 0$? If  you think this is not related, I can post another question

Comment: I don't see how this could be extended to handle that case. The question is certainly related, but I recommend posting another question about this

Comment: Thanks! I opened a new question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4388498/how-to-find-a-matrix-x-such-that-q-operatornamevecx-0-and-enforce-det

Comment: What if matrix $A$ has full column rank $n$? In that case $dim ker(A)=0$. I re-opened the question so that also other people can give a contribution, but I will accept your answer in a few days if I do not receive any other answer.

Comment: @VanBaffo If $A$ has full column-rank, then $AXB = 0$ holds iff $XB = 0$.

Comment: Are you aware of any technique which tries to approximate $AXB=0$ when all the three matrices are full column rank?

Comment: I don't understand what "approximating $AXB = 0$ when all three matrices are full column rank" is supposed to mean. Perhaps, given that $A$ and $B$ are of full rank, you are looking for an invertible $X$ such that $AXB$ is as close as possible to zero. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Comment: This also doesn't quite make sense without a further constraint. For example, say that the (spectral or Frobenius) norm of $X$ must be equal to $1$. Even so, the set of possible $X$ is not topologically closed. If the problem without the invertibility constraint has a non-invertible minimizer, then arbitrary close invertible approximations to this will yield progressively smaller errors.

Comment: So what would be your suggestion to solve such a problem? Suppose I can add both norm constraints and determinant constraints.

Comment: @VanBaffo I'm not sure. Perhaps that's worth a new question of its own.

Comment: I have added a new question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4389314/solving-equation-a-1xb-1-a-2xb-2-on-x-subject-to-constraint-on-x