# How to find a matrix $X$ such that $Q \operatorname{vec}(X)=0$ and enforce $det(X) \neq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, svd, singular-values

Assume (homogeneous) system of linear equations in $X$ of the form $Q\operatorname{vec}(X)=0$, where $Q$ is in general a tall non-square matrix. I want to find a **non-trivial** matrix $X$ (i.e. $X \neq 0$). A possible solution is given by constraining matrix $X$ to have unitary norm, i.e., $\|X\|_F^2=1$. A possible solution is given by a right eigenvector of the matrix $Q$ associated to a zero singular value.

But how can I enforce other kind of constraints, for instance that $\operatorname{det}(X) \neq0$? Do I have any closed form solution like the SVD above?

Comment: Regarding connecting this post to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4388268/81360), it might be helpful to write $Q$ as a sum $Q = \sum_i B^\top \otimes A_i$. For one, a simultaneous solution to $A_iXB_i = 0$ for all $i$ would satisfy your equation, but this is not a necessary condition for a solution $X$.

Comment: Do you miss a subscript $i$ on the $B$ inside the sum. I might reach sum ok Kronecker products. What if one term of the sum is subtracted instead of added? That is I have $B_1^\top \otimes A_1 - B_2^\top \otimes A_2$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Subtracting makes no difference; 
$$
B_1^\top \otimes A_1 - B_2^\top \otimes A_2 = B_1^\top \otimes A_1 + (-B_2)^\top \otimes A_2 $$

Comment: What about a more general $Q$?

Comment: Every $Q$ can be written as such a sum for some choice of matrices $A_i,B_i$.

Comment: Yes, but as you mention, by using that approach you can find some of the possible solutions. In my case, I cannot achieve that $A_iXB_i=0$ for every $i$. Perhaps the sum can achieve it, so I would like to find a more general expression.

Answer (score 0):

It is **impossible** to fulfill the requirements in general. We will see this in the following example.

Let $Q$ be the matrix below:
$$
Q=\begin{bmatrix}1& 0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&1&0&1\\
1&1&0&1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$
The three rows are important information. The rest of the rows are to make the matrix tall.
Let $\textrm{vec} X = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\\ x_4 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $Q \textrm{vec}X=0$ gives $x_1=x_2=x_4=0$ and $x_3$ is free.

We have
$$
X=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & x_3 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
will always have $\det X=0$.