# Solving equation $A_1XB_1 = A_2XB_2$ on $X$ subject to constraint on $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, svd

I have a system of equation on the $n \times n$ variable $X$ of the form:

$$A_1XB_1 = A_2XB_2$$
where $A_1, A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, with $m>n$ and $B_1, B_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with $n > p$.We can assume that $A_i, B_i$ are full column-rank.

I would like to solve the system of equation with the constraint on $X$ to be different from the trivial solution $X=0$, as well as det$(X)\neq 0$. Other constraints on $X$ might also be possible. How to proceed?

By defining $x= \operatorname{vec}(X)$ we can rewrite the system of equation as

$$\underbrace{(B_1^\top \otimes A_1 - B_2^\top \otimes A_2)}_{Q}x=0.$$

In order for the system to be solvable, matrix $Q$ needs to have a nullspace different from the $0$ vector alone. For instance, by adding the constraint $\|x\|=1$ I can solve (or at least approximate) the system by taking $x$ as the right singular vector of matrix $Q$ associated to the smallest singular value. But what if I would like to enforce the $X$ to have a determinant different from zero?

Comment: I was wrong, that actually is fine

Comment: Perhaps you should approach this as a generalized eigenvalue problem
$$
M_k = B^T_k\otimes A_k \quad\implies\quad
M_1x = \lambda M_2 x
$$
where you are interested in all eigenvectors associated with $\lambda=\tt1$. If more than one such eigenvector exists you can linearly combine them to create an $X$ matrix which has the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to your previous question, we cannot achieve $\det X\neq 0$ in general.

For example, take $m=4$, $n=2$, $p=1$.
$$
A_1= \begin{bmatrix} 1&0\\0&1\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, B_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
A_2= \begin{bmatrix} 2&0\\0&2\\0&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}, B_2=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then $$X=\begin{bmatrix} x_1&x_3\\ x_2&x_4\end{bmatrix}$$ in the equation
$$
A_1XB_1=A_2XB_2
$$
satisfies
$$
x_1=x_2=0. 
$$

This is because
$$
A_1XB_1=A_1\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1\\ x_2 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}, \ \ A_2XB_2=A_2\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2x_1\\ 2x_2 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus, any solution to the above equation satisfies $\det X=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have possible suggestions in how to solve this problem in an optimization based approach to at least approximate the solution?

Comment: Also, this is just one example. So it might not generalize I guess

Comment: My example shows this is impossible in general. If you want $\det X\neq 0$, you need to impose some more conditions on matrices $A_i, B_i$.

Comment: And I would like to know what optimization problem that you are interested in by solving this problem.

Comment: The context of the optimization problem is really specific, that would not help. I can tell something more on the matrices involved, if you think you might have time to look at them